# VBA to unzip file in Outlook

Tags: vba, unzip

Does any have VBA code for outlook that will automatically unzip a file? I have found several post that save a file to a locationm, but nothing that unzips a file.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe [this](http://www.rondebruin.nl/win/s7/win002.htm) is what you are looking for. An example from the website (visit the link to find out more):

> > With this example you can browse to the zip file. After you select the zip file the macro will create a new folder in your DefaultFilePath and unzip the Zip file in that folder. You can run the code without any changes.

```
Sub Unzip1()
    Dim FSO As Object
    Dim oApp As Object
    Dim Fname As Variant
    Dim FileNameFolder As Variant
    Dim DefPath As String
    Dim strDate As String

    Fname = Application.GetOpenFilename(filefilter:="Zip Files (*.zip), *.zip", _
                                        MultiSelect:=False)
    If Fname = False Then
        'Do nothing
    Else
        'Root folder for the new folder.
        'You can also use DefPath = "C:\Users\Ron\test\"
        DefPath = Application.DefaultFilePath
        If Right(DefPath, 1) <> "\" Then
            DefPath = DefPath & "\"
        End If

        'Create the folder name
        strDate = Format(Now, " dd-mm-yy h-mm-ss")
        FileNameFolder = DefPath & "MyUnzipFolder " & strDate & "\"

        'Make the normal folder in DefPath
        MkDir FileNameFolder

        'Extract the files into the newly created folder
        Set oApp = CreateObject("Shell.Application")

        oApp.Namespace(FileNameFolder).CopyHere oApp.Namespace(Fname).items

        'If you want to extract only one file you can use this:
        'oApp.Namespace(FileNameFolder).CopyHere _
         'oApp.Namespace(Fname).items.Item("test.txt")

        MsgBox "You find the files here: " & FileNameFolder

        On Error Resume Next
        Set FSO = CreateObject("scripting.filesystemobject")
        FSO.deletefolder Environ("Temp") & "\Temporary Directory*", True
    End If
End Sub
```